# Folding with 3 of a kind on the flop?

Tags: poker-strategy

I'm a decent poker player, but get pushed out of pots too easily and often don't know when to hold and raise.

I had J 6 and the flop was JJQ giving me 3 of a kind.  Well a guy raised $80 (2-5 NL)and I folded because I thought he either had a J with higher kicker or two Q's.  I felt so stupid when he just had a queen.  Was this a horrible fold by Me?

Comment: Any more info on the player you were facing? Flesh out the details a little. Thanks.

Comment: I had only been playing for a few hours.  My table had aggressive players and he was a quitter one, but I didn't Pin him as tight.

Comment: What was the action pre flop?   If you thought he could have QQ then how are you even in the hand with J6?

Comment: That's why you try not to play hands like J6, so you won't be faced with decisions like this. If you were forced to play it (say for free in the blinds), then your potential losses from folding in these situations is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

I gave you day to post pre flop action.  So now you have it.

A decent player would not post a question without relevant information.  Pre flop action and position is very important here.

If they flatted to slow play QQ here then they got you. QQ is one of the worse hands to slow play.  If they raised pre you should have foldedJ J6 even if it was suited.

If they had QQ why in the world would they raise with the nuts?  OK JJ is the nuts - did you raise pre?  They would put in a small bet or just check back hoping to get action on the turn.

It would be hard for me to find a situation where fold here is the proper play.

Maybe they flatted KJ, QJ pre.  Those hands should still check the flop.  J8 is a split if 9 or better comes up.

In summary even absent relevant information yes it looks like bad play.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, pre-flop action is important here, plus how many players are at the table. If the villain flats a min raise pre, there's no way he has QQ.

Without anymore info, I feel that re-raising is the best play in your position.

Comment: I witnessed a wonderful play by a friend of mine, while playing at the same table in a CG. He did exactly that UTG+1 with AA, caught 2 then 1 player that he hooked all the way down to winning a very decent pot. No one had been able to tell what his hand was 'til showdown... Very risky business, but hey, no pain, no gain :)

Comment: Yep, you got your hand totally obscured that way. I would never flat with AA with more than 2 people limping in front of me though. That just backfires way too often.

Comment: @OldPadawan So it was a wonderful play.  Does not make it profitable long term.

Comment: Well, no need to argue here, and it's not the place to do so, but **it is** EV+ because people never know how you'll play: standard, tight, loose or goofy... and this friend was always mixing styles and play, doing really good ;)

Comment: My only other concern in that position is that whilst your opponent may have no idea you got aces, you equally have no idea what they are holding.

Answer (score 0):

I think aggressive players take advantage of their aggression to mix up good and bad hands. If he had QQs he would have played it like any other hand or most probably with even more aggression .

Generally players tend to bet big on paired board(mostly when the preflop bet was aggressive) on flop because its very unlikely that the opponent has a piece of that flop, if they hit the pair on the flop with a decent kicker(8s to As,in my opinion) then they will continue to show their aggression to get value from A highs and worse kickers.

Here I think you should have flat called and let him lead on the turn again, turn could have bring some exciting cards. 
Other option is to raise, you can do this with the players who are neither very aggressive nor very tight . But its not rule of thumb.
Raising to a tight player on that board will give you some info about his hand , if he's trying to get you off your hand, he would probably fold to a raise.
Aggressive players won't give up  their pair on this board(in most cases).

Now, all these things also depend on what kind of player you are or what story you've been selling to your opponents.

If you can figure out , what your opponents think about your playing style then you can mixup your moves and their behaviors to win big pots.

Hope this helps.

P.S. : Pardon my English.